# REST Api user login

Tags: 8

I'm working on a react-native application with a clean D8 setup. I'm new to both. For some reason, my asyncstorage is being cleared on the emulator so I land on the login page even though I have an active session. So requesting a login returns a `403 - This route can only be accessed by anonymous users.` which is the normal behaviour. However, the app does not know who the user is or has any details regarding the user apart from the `xcsrf` token. I've figured, posting to `user?_format=json` redirects to the profile page of the user but the data returned is the html document.

How do I go about retrieving the details of the current logged in user without knowing their details? I'm ideally looking for a solution without any development on Drupal.

// Login

```
_authLogin = () => {
    // api = axios
    api({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/user/login?_format=json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token' : this.props.xcsrf,
        },
        data: { "name": this.state.username, "pass": this.state.password }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        this.props.saveUserSession(response.data).then((data) => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthLoading');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({ error })
        })
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response) {
            if( error.response.status == 403 ) {
                this._getLoggedInDetails();
            }
            // other error handling etc...
        } // other error handling etc...
    }.bind(this));
};

_getLoggedInDetails = () => {
    api({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/user?_format=json',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token' : this.props.xcsrf,
        },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        // returns 200
        // but <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" dir="ltr" ...
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function(error) {
        // handle errors
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I found a solution myself. There are 2 options;

1. Views

   - Create a new view with the user entity, set a filter criteria for logged in user and provide a rest export. This will return the current user object. So you can make a request to this when login returns a 403 so you can retrieve the details of the user.
2. Logout token

   - Apply [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3004421) patch to the user controller. This provides a new resource to get a logout token for the logged in user. So when login returns a 403, you can get a logout token at `session/logouttoken` and log the user out and login again.